# Percentage of value 0.0000001 .. 1000

Tags: c++

The logarithmic value of 0.000001 .. 1000 is -6 .. 3. Assume -6 is 0℅ and 3 is 100℅. How is the right formula to convert now a value x in ℅?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get from `.000001` to `-6` and `1000` to `3`, you'll want `std::log10` from `<cmath>`.

To convert `-6 ... 3` to `0 ... 9`, add 6.

To convert `0 ... 9` to a percentage, multiply by `100./9.`.

The `℅` symbol means care-of, not to be confused with the `%` symbol.